# Looking for the right stats test for my project

Tags: time-series, t-test, difference-in-difference

I hope someone could help me out and find the appropriate statistics test for my question.

I have national incidence rates (per 100,000) before and after a policy change for several countries and I want to know whether there is a **significant difference** of incidence rates after the change. As this is the same population, I know it is not 2 independent slopes.

Can someone please tell me if I should be using a paired T test? Or what test I can use to compare the slopes before and after?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome. Do all countries become exposed to the policy over time?

Comment: Yes they are all exposed but at different years. I am analyzing each country independently. I forgot to mention that I have at least 3 data points before and 3 time points after the change for each country

Comment: So you don't observe outcomes for any countries over time *never* exposed to the policy?

Comment: No I am only examining the individual countries who made a change to their national policy

Comment: Is there sufficient variation in the start (or end) times of treatment *across* the different countries? Also, is this a dichotomous treatment, or do some countries receive different intensity levels of the exposure?

Comment: I am not comparing across countries. This is a national policy change not a treatment therefore all countries receive the same "dosage"

Comment: So then each country is exposed to different policies? Also, when I say "treatment" I am referring to your policy.

Comment: No they all made the same policy change. To give context, all countries are changing their national policies from mass vaccination to selected vaccination for specific groups.

Comment: I recommend organizing your data into a panel. You have repeated observations on each country before *and* after the policy. You do not have to run a separate analysis for each country individually. Have you considered a regression formulation or any panel data estimators?

Comment: Would you recommend linear regression and comparison of slopes? I still want to run individual analyses as the countries are heterogenous in terms of location

Comment: In a regression context you could adjust for geography and any other *fixed* characteristics specific to your countries. Also, do you observe data at any lower level? For instance, did the policy only impact senior citizens in particular countries?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is aggregated up to the country level, then your options are limited. I recommend organizing your data into a panel structure as you have repeated observations on countries over time. Given the staggered adoption periods, you could estimate the following two-way fixed effects equation:

$$
\text{Rate}_{it} = \sum_i \text{Country}_i + \sum_t \text{Year}_t + \delta \text{Policy}_{it} + u_{it}
$$

where the summations denote a full series of indicators (i.e., fixed effects) for all countries $i$ and years $t$, respectively. If treatment is binary, then $\text{Policy}_{it}$ is equal to 1 if a country is a treated country *and* in a post-treatment time period, 0 otherwise. Since all countries eventually become exposed to the policy, then it should index all years where the policy 'turns on' (i.e., switches from 0 to 1) in the respective country. Here, $\delta$ is your causal estimand, but note that the equation is identified only off the variation in the *timing* of policy adoption *across countries*.

The foregoing equation is a generalization of the canonical "difference-in-differences" estimator. It accommodates designs where units may implement their policies at different times. Note, $\text{Policy}_{it}$ is not an indicator of 'group' status (i.e., treatment group versus control group). Rather, it is a policy dummy 'turning on' (i.e., switching from 0 to 1) for adopter countries *and* only during the years when the policy is in effect. Even though all countries become exposed, we still have variation in *treatment timing*. This is the extra layer of variation we can exploit in the absence of a viable control group.

In spite of the staggered variation present in your setting, I would highly recommend acquiring data on countries never espousing the policy. As it pertains to the coding of $\text{Policy}_{it}$, all non-adopter countries should be coded 0 in all years. They serve as your baseline history of never receiving a treatment. In practice, I recognize the difficultly of identifying a control group post-hoc. If you cannot acquire a suitable counterfactual, then identification of a "program effect" must rely on the *relative* time differences *across countries* reflecting the observed onset of the policy.

I must caution you that in order to use this approach, you must defend two positions. First, you must ensure that no other concurrent reforms were in effect which might confound the effects of the vaccination policy. Second, you should observe little evidence of *pre-trends*. Note that early-adopter countries serve as counterfactuals for late-adopter countries. Heterogeneous effects might offset parallel trends in subsequent policy adoption periods. Once a country is exposed to the policy, it must only experience a sharp jump in its average outcome; this level shift should be immediate—and persistent—however it should not set a country on a completely differently growth trajectory. In other words, we still assume a stable time evolution after the introduction of the policy.

Other possibilities include exploiting differences in vaccination 'dosage' across countries. Even though the policy affects all countries, some may have experienced it with greater intensity. In this sense, it is permissible to dichotomize jurisdictions into 'low/high' intensity groups. The subset of countries comprising your 'low' intensity treatment group would serve as your reference.

I hope you find these suggestions useful.